# Linear maps on lattice points

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces

I'm looking at an exercise that reads:

**Problem.** Let $A = \begin{bmatrix}a & b\\c & d\end{bmatrix} \in GL(2, \mathbb{C})$ and $\Lambda = \langle z \mapsto z + \omega_1, z \mapsto z + \omega_2\rangle$ with $\omega_1, \omega_2$ linearly independent over $\mathbb{R}$. Prove that if $\Lambda = \langle z \mapsto z + \omega_1', z \mapsto z + \omega_2'\rangle$ where
$$
\begin{bmatrix}\omega_1'\\\omega_2'\end{bmatrix} = A\begin{bmatrix}\omega_1\\\omega_2\end{bmatrix}
$$
then $A \in GL(2, \mathbb{Z})$ with $\det(A) = \pm1$.

The solutions state that clearly $A \in GL(2, \mathbb{Z})$ otherwise $A$ doesn't take lattice points to lattice points, which I don't follow—being a linear map, wouldn't $A$ take lattice points to lattice points anyway?

Comment: If the matrix $A$ does not have integer entries, then the entries of the vector $A\begin{bmatrix}\omega_1 \\ \omega_2\end{bmatrix}$ won't be integer linear combinations of $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ and therefore won't be elements of the lattice $\{n\omega_1+m\omega_2 : m,n \in \Bbb{Z}\}$.

Comment: Ah, yes, I'd missed that $\omega_1, \omega_2$ and $\omega_1', \omega_2'$ spanned the same lattice, which caused the confusion. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $A$ is not an element of $GL(2, \mathbb{Z})$. There are 2 cases here, firstly when $A$ does not have integer entries and secondly when $A$ does not have determinant $\pm 1$.

In the first case we know that $\omega_1' = a\omega_1 + b\omega_2$ and $\omega_2' = c\omega_1 + d\omega_2$. But if one of $a, b, c, d$ is not an integer then the corresponding $\omega_i'$ is not contained in $\Lambda$ (since $\Lambda$ consists of the sums $n\omega_1 + m\omega_2$ with $n, m \in \mathbb{Z}$).

In the second case the map is not surjective on lattice points.